# R metafor forestplot how to add CI 95% title above the column

Tags: r, r-forestplot, metafor

how to add title: "OR [CI 95%]" above confidence interval column (3d column) and title "Cohort" above the first column?

This is my code:

```
library(metafor)

y <- scan(what=numeric())
0.9158 
0.6304

se <- scan(what=numeric())
-0.08461987
-0.165519


meta_analysis <- rma(y,se^2,method="REML")

forest.rma(meta_analysis,xlab="Odds Ratio", slab=c("GoKind","EDIC"))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
forest.rma(meta_analysis,xlab="Odds Ratio", slab=c("GoKind","EDIC"))
text(-0.4, 4, "Cohort", pos=1)
text( 1.85, 3.5, "OR [95% CI]", pos=2)
```

first and second values in text are specifying distance along x and y axis